# Firestore performance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to set a collection to have integer ids in all its documents? I am looking for something like the autoincrement id of SQL tables.
If not, which of these options have better performance?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // option 1
    firestore.collection("documents").doc(`${i}`).set(documents[i])
    // option 2
    firestore.collection("documents").add({ intId: i })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not provide any sort of autoincrement IDs.  Those do not scale in the way that Firestore requires.

Both options you show have the same performance characteristics.  The limiting factor here is described in the [documentation about hotspotting](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots) behavior on document writes:

> Avoid high read or write rates to lexicographically close documents, or your application will experience contention errors.

This is exactly what your code is doing.  It's suggested that you use random IDs rather than sequential IDs, since sequential IDs don't scale well for Firestore.

You should read more of the linked documentation to learn more specifically about hotspotting.